# An orientable manifold which does not admit a non degenerate $2$- form

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

What is an example of  an orientable manifold of dimension greater than $1$ such that  it does mot admit a nondegenerate $2$-form?

Answer (score 2):

Existence of a non-degenerate $2$-form requires the dimension to be even. Thus $\mathbb R^3$ is an example. If $\omega$ is a non-degenerate $2$-form on a manifold $M$ of dimension $2n$, then $n$-fold wedge product of $\omega$ is a volume form. Hence $M$ is orientable. Therefore there is no non-degenerate $2$-form on the Mobius strip or on the real projective plane. If $M$ is orientable and compact, then the cohomology class of $\omega^n$ is nonzero. Therefore the same is true for $\omega$, so the second Betti number of $M$ is nonzero. In particular the only sphere admitting a non-degenerate $2$-form is $S^2$.

**Note** It was pointed out in the comments that the part about the second cohomology class is false, as I have implicitly assumed that the form under question is closed, hence symplectic.

Comment: The last part of your answer is true for *closed* nondegenerate 2-forms. Indeed a nonclosed 2-form has no reason to determine a (nonzero) cohomology class. In fact the existence of a nondegenerate 2-form amounts to the existence of an almost-complex structure, as proved in McDuff-Salamon's *Introduction to Symplectic Topology*. E.g. $S^3 \times S^1$ admits an almost-complex structure hence a nondegenerate 2-form (which might be deduced from the fact that it's parallelizable), and $S^2$ and $S^6$ are the only spheres to support nondegenerate 2-forms (which are necessarily not closed for $S^6$).

Comment: @JordanPayette  Thanks for your helpful comment. Yes of course in the question I did not assume that the form is closed

Comment: @JordanPayette of course, you are right. I have implicitly assumed that the form under question is closed without writing this down.